# Sync Framework Resources

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework, occasionallyconnected

I am looking for resources on Microsoft Sync Framework. Although MSDN and Google Search gave me the brief overview, I want some demos and presentations.

Also, is Live Mesh based on Sync Framework?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe those links will be helpful:

- [Sync101 - Getting Started with Sync](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sync/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=615)
- [Tutorial - Microsoft Sync Framework Basics](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sync/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=949)
- S[QL Express - Client Synchronization Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sync/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1200)
- [Sync Services for ADO.NET v2 - Download Only Sync](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ProjectName=sync&ReleaseId=1344)
- [Sync Services for ADO.NET Adapter Builder](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ProjectName=sync&ReleaseId=1343)

Answer (score 1):

Live Mesh isn't based on the Sync Framework, although they both use FeedSync. There is collaboration between Live Mesh (Live Framework) and Sync Framework to develop a Live Framework provider for V2 of the Sync Framework. See the following presentation for details:

http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL30/

Answer (score 1):

Sync Framework 2.0 has been released and the related [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902854(SQL.105).aspx) includes lots of examples.

Comment: any update for now , .net framework 4.5, what should we use now.

Answer (score 0):

For using NoSQL DB, couchbase mobile supports sync with couchbase server through Sync Gateway.  Very scalable solution.  http://www.couchbase.com/mobile#sync-gateway.