# How to sync a azure sql database into windows phone 8 local database?

Tags: sql, azure, windows-phone-8, synchronization

I need to sync an azure database into my windows phone 8 application's local database. New data is only inserted into azure database. So it is kind of one way synchronization. How can I do it? Kindly inform me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Microsoft Sync Framework:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/240071/1384539

http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/pdc2008/tl30

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902854%28SQL.105%29.aspx

Comment: Sync Framework OOTB doesn't support Windows Phone. You have to use the Sync Framework Toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at: [Sync Toolkit Windows 8 WinRT Windows Phone 8](https://syncwinrt.codeplex.com/)